# One to many Relation typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to create a one-to-many relationship between two tables in typerom (sqlite)
But
This creates an error

Error
**Entity metadata for Todo#menus was not found.**

My Entity Todo

```
    @Entity('Todo')
export class Todo{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id:number

@Column()


text:string

@Column({default:false})

completed:boolean

@Column({nullable:true})

completeTime : Date


@CreateDateColumn()

createTime:Date

@UpdateDateColumn()

updateTime:Date

 @OneToMany(type => Menu,menu => menu.todo)

  menus:Menu[]
  }
```

Menu Entity =>

```
 @Entity('Menu')
export  class Menu{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()

    id : number

    @Column()

    Name_Category_Restourent : String 

    @Column()

    Name_Category_Sandewith : String ;

    @Column()

    Name_Category_Drink : String
     @ManyToOne(type=>Todo , todo => todo.menus)
     todo : Todo ;
}
```

And Config

```
imports:[
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type:'sqlite',
        database : 'app.db',
        entities:[__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
        synchronize:true
    
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
        Todo,
        Menu
    ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming when the entities are not imported or configured incorrectly.

Please update the config like below:

```js
imports:[
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type:'sqlite',
        database : 'app.db',
        // it seems the path is not correct
        // so you can just import your entities directly here
        entities:[Todo, Menu],
        synchronize:true
    
    })
```

Comment: i do it but this error == > No repository for [Enitity] was found

Comment: No repository for "user" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Comment: The problem was solved
Thankful
The problem was that I had forgotten a module: D